# jquery radiobutton to trigger checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have some radiobutton and when I click some of radio button it also giving check into some checkbox, how I can do it in web programming?

so the scenario is have 3 radiobutton master,admin and custom. And I have several checkbox (access to a, to b, to c ,to d)
when I click radiobutton admin then below there checkbox for access to b , to c will be checked while access to a and to d checkbox will be uncheck

it's easy to do in desktop programming but I don't know how to that in web programming

Comment: I would recommend going to jQuery.com and doing some reading, this task is not very difficult to accomplish so you should be able to figure it out on your own very past. I will suggest using `.click` method and you are on your way. best of luck.

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? Binding event handlers? Traversing the DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```
Master <input type="radio" name="accesstype" data-access-type="master"/><br />
Admin <input type="radio" name="accesstype" data-access-type="admin"/><br />
Custom <input type="radio" name="accesstype" data-access-type="custom"/><br />

<div>
    To A <input class="access" type="checkbox" data-access-master=""/><br />
    To B <input class="access" type="checkbox" data-access-admin=""/><br />
    To C <input class="access" type="checkbox" data-access-admin=""/><br />
    To D <input class="access" type="checkbox" data-access-custom=""/><br />
    To E <input class="access" type="checkbox" data-access-custom="" data-access-master=""/><br />
    To F <input class="access" type="checkbox" data-access-admin="" data-access-master=""/><br />
    To G <input class="access" type="checkbox" data-access-admin="" data-access-custom=""/><br />
</div>
```

then

```
jQuery(function () {
    var $checks = $('input.access');
    $('input[type="radio"][data-access-type]').change(function () {
        var type = $(this).data('accessType');
        $checks.filter('[data-access-' + type + ']').prop('checked', true)
        $checks.not('[data-access-' + type + ']').prop('checked', false)
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MpAG4/)

Answer (score 0):

Raido buttons that have the same name are built as a set (or array) on the page. Using jQuery you can bind the change event of this array (triggering when one of the radio buttons is clicked):

```
$( document ).ready -> 
  $('input[name=some_name]').change ->
    if ($('input[name=some_name]:checked').val() == "admin"
      $("#checkbox_1").prop('checked', false)
      $("#checkbox_2").prop('checked', true)
      ...
    if ....
    .
    .
    .
```

You will have to set your HTML with corresponding values and ids. I am assuming you know how to do that, although from your question I am guessing you might be very new to web development (if so, welcome!). I think if the code and terminology you see here are too complicated for you, try to do some more reading first.

**Note:** I am using coffescript to write my javascript here because it is easier on the eyes